# How to Redirect a page, outside of an Iframe using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

These are the Pages in the application

1. Login.aspx ( doesnt use any master )
2. Home.aspx (Uses the master).

There is an IFrame in the master which loads all the webpages like page1.aspx, page2...
When a user is browsing say page1.aspx and session expires, the login page loads inside the IFrame, whereas, it should load externally, I mean outside of the iFrame.

I hope my question made some sense

```
Page_Init()
{
  if(Session["user"]==null)
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/Forms/Login.aspx");
   }
}
```

There are solutions here for JS as window.top.location.href="..", but dont know how to implement.
how to fix this using C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
Page_Init()
{
  if(Session["user"]==null)
   {
      string jScript = "window.top.location.href = '/Forms/Login.aspx';";
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "forceParentLoad", jScript, true);
      //Response.Redirect("~/Forms/Login.aspx");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways if we uses client side scripts but by using **Non Client Side Scripts**:

```
<a href="location" target="_top">Click here to continue</a> 

<a href="location" target="_parent">Click here to continue</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

An aspx page within an Iframe has no reference to it's parent without using javascript. Therefore, you will need to implement it as javascript.

If the session expires, you could simply write out the JS at the same point you were attempting to Response.Redirect and it should work fine.